# C# How to wrap date string in single quote inside the string's double quotes

Tags: c#, date, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to wrap my DateTime's date format in single quotes

e.g. DateTime.Now().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") output will be like "2017-03-30"

My question, Is there anyway of producing the result like "'2017-03-30'" (i-e single quotes within the double quotes)?

Comment: Have you tried concatenation or interpolation (C#6)?

Comment: concatenation didn't work.

Comment: Concatenate the result, not the formatter...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx), or on C#6+ [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn961160.aspx):

```
// String format
string.Format("'{0}'", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

// Interpolation
$"'{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}'";
```

Result:

> '2017-03-30'

Comment: Hurray... Thanks Equalsk. your string format approach worked fine. I am sure Interpolation will also be ok.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Please press the tick to accept when you have time ;-)

Comment: I think I accidentally made that mistake but not sure though. You need to raise your concern to clear the down vote as there is no reason for your answer to be down voted. It is definitely a mistake.

Comment: It's easy to tell which way you voted, the arrows on the left are either orange or grey. Orange shows whether you voted up or down. Up is good, down is bad. You should be able to change it by just clicking on the up arrow.

Comment: I know the representation. I meant to check the tick not to vote when I accepted your answer. I have corrected that though.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `string.Format`:

```
string.Format("'{0:yyyy-MM-dd}'", DateTime.Now)
```